# How to prevent access to SSAS through visual studio?

Tags: powerbi, ssas, cube, ssas-tabular

I have a typical fact table with dimensions **Project**, **Profit Center**, etc

In a report, I have a **table visual** that shows individual numbers; and another table shows the department numbers…

It looks something like this:

[image]

(Left: personal numbers. Right: department numbers)

My goal is that Tim shouldn’t be able to see someone else’s number, but he definitely can (and should) see the aggregated numbers for his department.

I realized that someone accessing from PowerBI or excel can connect to the model and play with the tables, pick another name and see someone else’s number, therefore I have hidden most tables...

But now, I just realized, someone with access can connect from Visual Studio to the SSAS:
[image]

The person can open the .bim, unhide all tables, and with the “analyze from excel” option in VS see any numbers…

**Is there any way to avoid/prevent this?**

**More info:**

My model:
[image]

(**Project** table has columns Lead1,Lead2,Lead3,Lead4,Lead5 and Lead6… **Engagement Role** is just an unpivot of this).

On my left visual I have:

[image]

(triggering a more restrictive access).

My RLS:
[image]

Comment: When you mention open the bim file, is it they connect to the server and import a copy of it, or do they have access to the project file?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to avoid/prevent this?

RLS will be enforced from every client experience, but RLS is never enforced for Workspace members with higher than Viewer permissions.  See [Using RLS with workspaces in Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/enterprise/service-admin-rls#using-rls-with-workspaces-in-power-bi)

And hiding tables and columns is not a security measure.  Hidden tables and columns can be used in DAX queries and measures.